# Pink and green horizontal lines on the top of the screen

Tags: windows-10, freeze, troubleshooting, display-driver, laptop-display

Three days ago suddenly my laptop screen started freezing up.It freezes intermittently say for 5 seconds and then is okay on its own.Then within a minute this repeats.Simultaneously I have pink and green horizontal lines flashing on the to of my screen while this freezing is going on.
My screen is completely the same as it was before.No BSOD (blue screen) except for being freezed up for a few seconds with these lines on the top
I have tried -

- System Restore to an earlier date when it used to work fine
- Uninstalling my Display Driver and Reinstalling it
- Completely uninstalling my Display Driver (My current situation i.e its running on the Microsoft basic display adapter)
- I have also looked up this on the web but couldn't find any definite/working solution.

FYI: This intermittent flashing of horizontal green and pink lines **occurs** in the *safe mode* restart of the PC and the *boot menu* as well.

PS: I have Dell Inspiron 5558 Windows 10 OS with Intel Core processor.

**EDIT**: I just noticed while freezing the screen changes from being smooth to that of a very fine pixel grid.It then again smoothens when the screen unfreezes.

**EDIT-2** Today the screen went translucent white *intermittently* with lots of horizontal pink and green lines.Sometimes it also goes opaque but mostly its translucent with these lines.It occurs for say 4 seconds and the display is okay except for the earlier mentioned freezing.

Can anyone tell me what is actually the problem ? Hardware or Software ? How can I fix this ? At least, can anyone help me find the trigger/cause ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could be the screen, display cable, or graphics card. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: So its a hardware problem ?I would try but on account of COVID19 lockdowns, I don't thing I would be able to anytime soon.Can something be done at home ?